# Syntax to automatically generate a string on store in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

What would be the simplest and easiest way to generate a unique string (MD5(timestamp) or UUID) automatically on an insert in Laravel 5.

This is what I have right now.

My store function

```
public function store(AppointmentsRequest $request)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::create(Request::all());

    return redirect('appointments/'.$appointment->id );
}
```

My table schema (see **my_generated_string** column below)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('appointments', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->dateTime('appointment_at');

        $table->string('my_generated_string')->unique(); --> Want a generated string in here

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Notes about the solution**

@JamesFlight provided an excellent solution to my problem.

uniqid() generates a string (13 characters long) based on current time in microseconds. Since two users of my app could (slim chance but..) create an appointment at the exact same time, and this column must be unique in my database, I've added the user_id prefix in front of the generated string. Since it's impossible for one user to create two appointments on the same microsecond, this should be enough for uniqueness in my app.

My function was changed to:

```
public static function create(array $attributes)
{
    return parent::create(
        array_merge(
            $attributes,
            ['my_generated_string' => uniqid(\Auth::user()->id, true)]
        )
    );
}
```

Note: `true` will make the string more unique by generating a 23 characters string instead of 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do this:

```
public function store()
{
    $appointment = Appointment::create(
        array_merge(
            Request::all(),
            ['my_generated_string' => uniqid()]
        )
    );

    return redirect('appointments/'.$appointment->id );
}
```

Or override the create method on `Appointment`:

```
class Appointment extends Model
{
    public static function create(array $attributes)
    {
        return parent::create(
            array_merge(
                $attributes,
                ['my_generated_string' => uniqid()]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! i've tried to override the create method, needed to add static in here: `public static function create`, but then got another error `Declaration of App\Appointment::create() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes)`

Comment: Good point, I typed that in a hurry. I'll correct the answer!

Comment: Just add in the array type hint as is now in the answer, and it should work.

Comment: It stores the row with an empty generated_string, and I get this `error ErrorException in AppointmentsController.php line 178: Trying to get property of non-object` . Line 178 is this line in my store method: `return redirect('appointments/'.$appointment->id );` From my create view, I'm passing client_id, user_id, appointment_at

Comment: Add the return keyword as is now in the answer which should fix the controller error. The `my_generated_string` column shouldn't be empty. Run `dd(uniqid())` to check it's actually generating something…

Comment: It finally worked! I had to add `my_generated_string` to my `protected $fillable` list defined in my model. thanks so much! What happens if the generated string is not unique in my table?

Comment: If the string was not unique then the db transaction will fail (because you called the `unique()` method for the column). However, i think the `uniqid()` function uses the current date/time to generate the value, so as long as two appointments are not created at the exact same millisecond, you should be fine. Worth noting: there are other libraries available for uuids in php e.g. https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: Super, thanks for helping me with this solution, I really appreciate.